Mongoose: Update an item in a nested array using current item data
Having the following documents in a collection:
const documents = [
    {
        _id: '1',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'plastic',
                color: 'blue',
                date: '2021-02-01',
                oldValues: [{ color: 'light-blue', date: '2021-01-01' }],
            },
            {
                type: 'plastic',
                color: 'black',
                date: '2021-03-01',
                oldValues: [
                    { color: 'white', date: '2021-01-01' },
                    { color: 'grey', date: '2021-02-01' },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        _id: '2',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'plastic',
                color: 'violet',
                date: '2021-02-01',
                oldValues: [{ color: 'pink', date: '2021-01-01' }],
            },
            {
                type: 'wood',
                color: 'black',
                date: '2021-03-01',
                oldValues: [
                    { color: 'white', date: '2021-01-01' },
                    { color: 'orange', date: '2021-02-01' },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

I want to find documents with an item with the type plastic and color black in the items field, update the color of that item to green, and keep a record of the current item in the oldValues field, like this:
[
    {
        _id: '1',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'plastic',
                color: 'blue',
                date: '2021-02-01',
                oldValues: [{ color: 'light-blue', date: '2021-01-01' }],
            },
            {
                type: 'plastic',
                color: 'green',
                date: '2021-03-01',
                oldValues: [
                    { color: 'white', date: '2021-01-01' },
                    { color: 'grey', date: '2021-02-01' },
                    { color: 'black', date: '2021-03-01' },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        _id: '2',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'plastic',
                color: 'violet',
                date: '2021-02-01',
                oldValues: [{ color: 'pink', date: '2021-01-01' }],
            },
            {
                type: 'wood',
                color: 'black',
                date: '2021-03-01',
                oldValues: [
                    { color: 'white', date: '2021-01-01' },
                    { color: 'orange', date: '2021-02-01' },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

For this, I wrote and ran the following query:
db.collection.update(
    { items: { $elemMatch: { color: 'black', type: 'plastic' } } },
    {
        $set: {
            'items.$[item].color': 'green',
            'items.$[item].date': '2021-04-01',
            'items.$[item].oldValues': {
                $concatArrays: [
                    { $ifNull: ['$items.$[item].oldValues', []] },
                    [{ color: '$items.$[item].color', date: '$items.$[item].date' }],
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'item.color': 'black', 'item.type': 'plastic' }] },
);

with this query, the color field of the interested item in the items field was updated but oldValues field was overwritten by the update terms:
const updatedDocumentsAfterRunningQuery = [
    {
        _id: '1',
        items: [
            {
                color: 'blue',
                date: '2021-02-01',
                oldValues: [{ color: 'light-blue', date: '2021-01-01' }],
                type: 'plastic',
            },
            {
                color: 'green',
                date: '2021-04-01',
                oldValues: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                        { $ifNull: ['$items.$[item].oldValues', []] },
                        [{ color: '$items.$[item].color', date: '$items.$[item].date' }],
                    ],
                },
                type: 'plastic',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        _id: '2',
        items: [
            {
                color: 'violet',
                date: '2021-02-01',
                oldValues: [{ color: 'pink', date: '2021-01-01' }],
                type: 'plastic',
            },
            {
                color: 'black',
                date: '2021-03-01',
                oldValues: [
                    { color: 'white', date: '2021-01-01' },
                    { color: 'orange', date: '2021-02-01' },
                ],
                type: 'wood',
            },
        ],
    },
];

Looks like operator $concatArrays is not detected by the $set operator.
Here is the link of MongoDb Playground.
How can I resolve this?
Update 1:
It would be great if we can do this in a transaction!
